# Performance testing of uploading a file

Tags: file-upload, performance-testing

I need to test the performance of uploading a file ( small and large )  is there any tools to suggest to do so

Comment: Did you try to google for any? If so please add them here too, otherwise please research before you post ;)

Comment: i have tried google could not find any , i need a tool just for file upload performance

Answer (score 0):

Try with Open Source Tool -  **Jmeter**